# How can I relate two models (django tutorial's Poll and Choice) in a Tastypie API

Tags: django, api, python-2.7, django-models, tastypie

I'm trying relate two resources (models) in an API using Tastypie but I'm getting an error.

I've followed the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/) and used:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I tried to create a link between the Poll and Choice based on this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582449/creating-related-resources-with-tastypie) and wrote the following code:

api.py

```
class ChoiceResource(ModelResource):
    poll = fields.ToOneField('contact.api.PollResource', attribute='poll', related_name='choice')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Choice.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'choice'

class PollResource(ModelResource):
    choice = fields.ToOneField(ChoiceResource, 'choice', related_name='poll', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Poll.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'poll'
```

When I go to: 127.0.0.1:8088/contact/api/v1/choice/?format=json

Everything works as it should. For example one of my choices links to the right poll:

```
{
    "choice_text": "Nothing", 
    "id": 1, 
    "poll": "/contact/api/v1/poll/1/", 
    "resource_uri": "/contact/api/v1/choice/1/", 
    "votes": 6
}
```

When I go to: 127.0.0.1:8088/contact/api/v1/poll/?format=json

I get:

```
{
    "error": "The model '<Poll: What's up?>' has an empty attribute 'choice' and doesn't allow a null value."
}
```

Do I need to use the fields.ToManyField instead or do I need to change my original model?

Answer (score 0):

[Tastypie recommends against creating reverse relationships](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#reverse-relationships) (what you're trying to do here the relationship is `Choice` -> `Poll` and you want `Poll` -> `Choice`), but if you still wanted to, you can.

Excerpt from the Tastypie docs:

> Unlike Django’s ORM, Tastypie does not automatically create reverse
>   relations. This is because there is substantial technical complexity
>   involved, as well as perhaps unintentionally exposing related data in
>   an incorrect way to the end user of the API.
>
> However, it is still possible to create reverse relations. Instead of
>   handing the ToOneField or ToManyField a class, pass them a string that
>   represents the full path to the desired class. Implementing a reverse
>   relationship looks like so:

```
# myapp/api/resources.py
from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from myapp.models import Note, Comment


class NoteResource(ModelResource):
    comments = fields.ToManyField('myapp.api.resources.CommentResource', 'comments')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Note.objects.all()


class CommentResource(ModelResource):
    note = fields.ToOneField(NoteResource, 'notes')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Comment.objects.all()
```